# How to make an html table with multi Styled imagen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I am facing a problem about image acomodation

The main objective is to reach this

```
---------------———————-
     Table header
----------------——————
| Img1 |      | img4 |
-------| Img3 |--—————
| Img2 |      | img5 |
```

Keeping that in mind, how can i do to make an image Table in order to put the images like that? It Is important to say that the images are optimized for those proportions.

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? It seems like you know you want a table. There are plenty of tutorials on the internet about creating tables like the one illustrated.

Comment: I know it is well done with divs, but i am figuring out how to do it with tables if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "TABLE-HEADER TABLE-HEADER TABLE-HEADER TABLE-HEADER" "IMG1 IMG3 IMG3 IMG4" "IMG2 IMG3 IMG3 IMG5";
}

.TABLE-HEADER { grid-area: TABLE-HEADER; }

.IMG3 { grid-area: IMG3; }

.IMG1 { grid-area: IMG1; }

.IMG2 { grid-area: IMG2; }

.IMG4 { grid-area: IMG4; }

.IMG5 { grid-area: IMG5; }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="TABLE-HEADER"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/650x200/000/fff"></div>
  <div class="IMG3"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff"></div>
  <div class="IMG1"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x200/000/fff"></div>
  <div class="IMG2"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x100/000/fff"></div>
  <div class="IMG4"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x200/000/fff"></div>
  <div class="IMG5"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x100/000/fff"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it finally worked, i was thinking on doing with tables but i think yours is a faster way to solve that

Comment: Glad I could help